# docx to markdown wrong line wrapping

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, docx, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a docx file (originally knitted from a Rmarkdown file) back to a Rmarkdown file and I'm having problems with the outcome line-wrapping. The original Rmarkdown file looks like this

````
---
title: "test"
author: "N."
date: "3/27/2020"
output: word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Some title

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id hendrerit urna. Pellentesque gravida rhoncus felis, id lacinia ligula feugiat vitae. Aenean faucibus quam ut turpis varius tincidunt. Integer mollis sem id massa porttitor, et eleifend augue laoreet. Morbi placerat posuere libero, bibendum iaculis velit mattis non. Duis quam enim, pretium vel laoreet eget, volutpat non diam. Duis consequat aliquet dignissim. In lacus orci, interdum ac sem eu, placerat venenatis lacus. Nulla facilisi. Nulla non sem ullamcorper, porttitor velit vitae, placerat ipsum. Etiam a quam at nisi condimentum ultricies. Fusce volutpat enim nec est cursus maximus. Aliquam rhoncus nibh nec risus feugiat, vel cursus felis ullamcorper. Aenean enim urna, iaculis in venenatis porta, elementum eget felis.
````

The knitted docx document looks fine and the line wrapping is maintained as in the original Rmarkdown file. However, then I convert the docx file back to Rmarkdown with the following R code:

```
pandoc_convert(input = 'docx_file.docx', to="markdown", output = "new.Rmd")
```

and I get a lot of extra line breaks. Something like this:

```
Some title
==========

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut id hendrerit
urna. Pellentesque gravida rhoncus felis, id lacinia ligula feugiat
vitae. Aenean faucibus quam ut turpis varius tincidunt. Integer mollis
sem id massa porttitor, et eleifend augue laoreet. Morbi placerat
posuere libero, bibendum iaculis velit mattis non. Duis quam enim,
pretium vel laoreet eget, volutpat non diam. Duis consequat aliquet
dignissim. In lacus orci, interdum ac sem eu, placerat venenatis lacus.
Nulla facilisi. Nulla non sem ullamcorper, porttitor velit vitae,
placerat ipsum. Etiam a quam at nisi condimentum ultricies. Fusce
volutpat enim nec est cursus maximus. Aliquam rhoncus nibh nec risus
feugiat, vel cursus felis ullamcorper. Aenean enim urna, iaculis in
venenatis porta, elementum eget felis.
```

This new line wrapping is (I guess) the result of how the text is displayed in the docx document. Because this new extra line breaks match how the docx file looks if you open it in Office, however there are no line breaks in that document. Also, this is true whether I knitted to `word_document` or `bookdown::word_document2`, and whether I convert back to `.Rmd` or `.md`.

**Is this normal behaviour? If so, is possible to keep the original line wrapping?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I actually found it searching for something else. The following produces my expected output.

```
pandoc_convert(input = 'docx_file.docx', to="markdown", output = "new.Rmd", options = c('--wrap=none'))
```